# Use Dell Technician Toolkit even if you aren't a technician

Tags: dell-inspiron

I was getting support with my dell machine yesterday, and I noticed that the technician used a program called TechnicianToolkit. I had found the file on my computer, but it crashes immediately after launch as admin. Is there a way I can use this software as a admin user instead of a dell technician? It is really helpful for a lot of problems I have on my computer.
[image]

Comment: Have you done any research regarding this? I would guess the application may have some sort of validation to confirm it is being run by a technician besides simply being run as admin.